# Удаляет все строки из бд

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Доброго времени суток.

У меня есть код

```
$cookie = explode("_", $_COOKIE['sc_user']);
$session_delete = $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `Sc_session` WHERE `uid` = '{$this->user->id}' AND 'hash' != '{$cookie[1]}'");
```

Получаем куки и разбиваем их на две части, первое это ID юзера и второе это хеш.

Запрос выполняется без проблем за исключением того, что он удаляет все записи найденные по столбцу UID, однако я хочу не затрагивать активную сессию и мне нужно что бы из бд не удалялась запись с хешем из куки, а все остальное удалилось, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Вы уверены что в`$cookie` и `$cookie[1]` что-то есть? может там пустая строка

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, уверен, полные куки имеют вид **id_hash**, например **1_dsahfjsad7sda7da8sf** , explode разбивает их на id и hash. Если вы про то, существуют ли куки вообще, то это я проверяю через панельку гугла, и там куки отображаются, тем более что авторизация на сайте так же проходит успешно

Comment: Это ваши **догадки**......Надо открыть отладчик PHP и убедиться в этом лично......2 шаг: вынести весь запрос в отдельную переменную и вставлять в query исключителньо эту переменную..... 3 шаг: посмотреть какую конкретно формирует строку ваш код.... 4 шаг - выполнить запрос отдельно в каком-нибудь СУБД и сравнить правильно ли вообще формирует запрос.......... шаг на будущее: использовать https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php   ....... на текущий момент это просто гадание на кофейной гуще. Проблема может быть именно в пустой переменной. Поэтому Debugging в руки

Answer (score -1):

```
$cookie = explode("_", $_COOKIE['sc_user']);
$active_session_hash = $cookie[1];
$session_delete = $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `Sc_session` WHERE `uid` = '{$this->user->id}' AND `hash` != '{$active_session_hash}'");
```

Comment: Постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Извините, а в чем собственно разница? Как это отличается от того что приведено в моем коде?